# Change default order of pages in WordPress Admin / Backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the default sorting order of the pages in my WordPress backend. I know this can easily be done by clicking on the tab "Title", "Date" or "ID" but those are merely one-time settings and I need a global = default solution.

I went ahead and tried using this function which to me makes perfect sense but it just doesn't work with WordPress 4.2.3 :-(

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {

global $pagenow;

if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {

    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $wp_query->set( 'order', 'asc' );       
}
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin', 5 );
```

Any idea why this is not working any more? How can I achieve that?

Thanks + regards,
Henning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change order "ASC" to "DESC" in your own code, it will work perfectly. Or copy and paste below mentioned code into your functions.php :

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {

global $pagenow;

if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {

    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );       
}
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin', 5 );
```

Comment: Hey Sunil, thanks for your suggestion!

I tried your code but no changes... Have you tried / verified it in your environment?

First of all it seems we'd need to use DESC instead of DSC, [see WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and secondly I don't care so much whether it is ascending or descending but the sorting just doesn't function at all...

Any further ideas?

Comment: @Leander thanks for updating me with wordpress codex and you are right. But I have already tested the code with one of my updated wordpress 4.2.3 before answering to you, infact I have created an article as well, you can see here : http://www.wptricks24.com/change-default-order-of-post-or-page-in-wordpress-admin/. May be there is any issue with your current theme, just switch your theme to default theme and then try.

Comment: I just tested it with another website / theme and you are right! No problem at all there, works fine. Will investigate further why this is in conflict with my current theme and get back to you / update this post. Thanks!

Comment: My bad... This code works fine, I just had "Post Types Order" installed and one setting in the options panel overrides the admin sort-ability... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet of code :

```
  function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {
    global $pagenow;
      if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DSC' );
      }
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin' );
```

Comment: Thanks – see my comment to Sunil's post above, same here.