# Change default sort order of pages in WordPress Admin [Update]

Tags: php, wordpress

Iterating an older question from 2015 [Change default order of pages in WordPress Admin / Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745482/change-default-order-of-pages-in-wordpress-admin-backend)

I am trying to achieve the same results as OP. The difference in outcome is that when I alter default sorting to be ordered by date, it will order table only by dates of top level posts which is different than ordering only by date.

When I order pages in admin manually by url param `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=date&order=desc`, it will ignore post levels and treat everything as top level pages. But the page levels get preserved when I change query orderby to date like this:

```
function set_post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin', 5 );
```

As the original post is quite old, maybe the right way to set default order is different than in past.

Looks like setting the primary column of the table could be the way, but I am not able to find the right hook for this. (When I change query oderby to date, primary column stays the same e.g. set to 'title' and it will still get the class 'sorted', contrary to ordering by url when 'sorted' class will be on 'date' column as it should be)